# Data reader Display issue

Tags: c#, database, winforms, sqldatareader

Using c# with a windows form to read data from a data base.

```
     while (reader.Read())
                {
                    textbox1.Text += reader["Person"] + reader["Occur"].ToString() + "\n";                    
                }
```

Can somebody clear up why this displays like:

```
    John
     8
```

Instead of:

```
    John 8
```

EDIT: these are just an example of what's in my database table

Comment: are they stored as strings in the database ? are there trailing carriage returns at the end of values in the person column.

Comment: Person is stored as string, Occur is stored as int

Comment: Don't know what carriage returns are? sorry i'm a newbie

Comment: @user1353517: What  Eoin Campbell wanted to say is that you probably have stored [carriage returns](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carriage) in your `Person` field. That would explain the word wrap after `reader["Person"]`.

Comment: @TimSchmelter ahh right ok. Is there any way to fix this?

Comment: Never mind, the answer below got it :)

Comment: @user1353517: You shouldn't store it. So before you store the person name, you should remove the carriage returns and line feeds from the end of the string: `name = name.TrimEnd('\r', '\n');`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that there is a carriage return stored with strings in the database.
so you can easily get rid of it.

```
textbox1.Text += reader["Person"].ToString().Trim() + reader["Occur"].ToString();
```